# How to write gamma in latex

Tags: symbols

I want to use the symbol gamma in the following document. But whenever i type \gamma , i get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 hello my boy!!!!!!!! \X
                           \gamma
?
```

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1 in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\maketitle
hello my boy!!!!!!!! \X\gamma
\end{document}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Put it in math mode: $\gamma$.

Comment: What is `\X` by the way?

Comment: @Au101 i don't know, i googled it and i found that line for gamma, so tried it out, but didnt work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is two-fold. Not only should `\gamma` be written using math-mode `$\gamma$`, but that `\X` is undefined.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world! $\gamma$
\end{document}
```

How to interpret the error message style of TeX is obtained by reading Chapter 6: Running TeX (p 31) in [the TeXbook](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook):

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.2 \vship
>            1in
> ?
> ```
>
> TeX begins its error messages with ‘`!`’, and it shows what it was
>   reading at the time of the error by displaying two lines of context.
>   The top line of the pair (in this case ‘`\vship`’ ) shows what TeX has
>   looked at so far, and where it came from (‘`l.2`’, i.e., line number 2);
>   the bottom line (in this case ‘`1in`’ ) shows what TeX has yet to read.

In your case, TeX's already read `\X` (the undefined control sequence), but not yet `\gamma`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\newcommand{\mygamma}{\ensuremath{\gamma{}}}

\begin{document}

\mygamma

\end{document}
```

or whatever you want to call it.